# Construct or prove existence of a certain quadrilateral

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, quadrilateral

I have three questions about a quadrilateral with the following properties:

- It is convex.
- It has exactly one pair of congruent opposite sides.
- It has exactly one pair of congruent opposite angles.
- It is not a parallelogram.

Does such a quadrilateral exist? Is it possible to construct such a quadrilateral with compass and straightedge? If the construction is not possible, why  not?

Comment: Note -- the "no parallelogram" restriction is redundant. Also, you the word "exactly" in the opposite angle condition isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such quadrilaterals exist -- even constructible ones.

For example, the quadrilateral $ABCD$ with
\begin{align*}
\angle DAB &= 60^\circ\\[6pt]
\angle ABD &= 45^\circ\\[6pt]
\angle ADB &= 75^\circ\\[6pt]
\angle BCD &= 60^\circ\\[6pt]
\angle CBD &= 105^\circ\\[6pt]
\angle CDB &= 15^\circ\\
\end{align*}

satisfies the required  conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Let ABC be an isosceles right triangle with AC = BC.  On base AB make BD = AC and join CD. Thus angle BCD = angle BDC = 67.5 degrees.  On CD, congruent to triangle CDB, construct triangle CDB' in a plane perpendicular to that of triangle ACD, forming quadrilateral ACB'D.  Since angle B'CA is less than 90 degrees (it's less than the angle AC makes with a perpendicular to the plane of ACD at A), while angle B'DA is greater than 90 degrees (it's greater than the angle AD makes with a perpendicular to ACD at D), these angles are not equal.  But angle CAD = opposite angle CB'D = 45 degrees.  And AC = opposite side B'D.  But AC is not parallel to B'D, since they are not co-planar, and for the same reason CB' is not parallel to AD.  Therefore, a quadrilateral ACB'D has been constructed (with straightedge and compass) in which only one pair of opposite sides and angles are equal, and which is not a parallelogram.