# Construct a quadrilateral, not a parallelogram, in which pair of opposite angles and a pair of opposite sides are equal.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples, quadrilateral

I want to construct a quadrilateral which is not a parallelogram, in which a pair of opposite angles and a pair of opposite sides are equal. I tried drawing one, but I am not able to. Please help. (And I dont think I will be able to post what I have tried or drawn. Hope the statement of the post is clear).

Umm, I understand that it might look like it is the duplicate of another similar question( I saw that post actually!). But I do not think it explained how to construct one. I know such a quadrilateral exists, that is not my real question. I want to know how it is constructed. I hope I made it clear.

Also, I wanted a short, simplified and clear solution for this(I can elaborate that).

Comment: Related/Duplicate: ["If a quadrilateral has a pair of equal opposite sides, and a pair of equal opposite angles, then is it necessarily a parallelogram?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2778045/409) and ["Construct or prove existence of a certain quadrilateral"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2104597/409). Perhaps others.

Comment: Is it fine now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\Delta ABK$ such that $\measuredangle ABK>90^{\circ}$ and let $D\in AK$ such that $BD=BK$.

Now, let $\Delta BDC\cong\Delta KBA$ such that $K$ and $C$ are placed in the same side respect to the line $DB$.

Thus, $ABCD$ is a needed quadrilateral because $AB=DC$ and $\measuredangle A=\measuredangle C$.

Easy to see that $ABCD$ is not parallelogram.

Comment: $ABCD$ will always turn out to be concave?( I mean, I get a concave quadrilateral, and the nomenclature also differs, thats why)

Comment: And also, can you explain how $\angle A$ = $\angle C$?

Comment: @Anu Radha Yes, it concave. The equality of angles follows from congruent triangles.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the resulting quadrilateral is _concave_ rather than being _convex_? Why can it NOT be convex?

Comment: Also, by $\angle A$ and $\angle C$, which two angles do you mean? I dont understand how equality follows from the congruency..(Sorry, really!)

Comment: @Anu Radha Since $\Delta BDC\cong\Delta KBA$, we get $\measuredangle BCD=\measuredangle KAB=\measuredangle DAB$ because $D\in AK$.

Comment: @Anu Radha $ABCD$ can be convex if you'll take $\measuredangle ABK<90^{\circ}$ and $BD=BK<AB$.

Answer (score 1):

You are not succeeding in finding such a quadrilateral because none exists. 
If $ABCD$ is such a quadrilateral with $|AD| = |BC|$ and $\beta = \delta$ then the triangles $ABC$ and $CDA$ are congruent. It follows that $\sphericalangle CAB = \sphericalangle DCA$, hence $AB$ is parallel to $DC$ from this you can easily deduce that the quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

Comment: They are not always congruent. See please my counterexample.